# compress vector in (inverse of rep)

Tags: r

I need to decompose a vector into a series of x and repeat, I am not really sure what the proper term for this is. It is the inverse of the `rep` function. So a vector

```
[1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2] -> [1x1, 4x2, 5x1, 2x2]
```

I wrote a little function to do this, but I am sure there must be a more native way:

```
invrep <- function(y){
  numy <- as.numeric(y);
  newpoints <- which(c(T,diff(numy) != 0));
  x <- y[newpoints];
  times <- diff(c(newpoints, length(numy)+1));
  return(list(x=x, times=times));
}

myvec <- factor(floor(runif(50,0,3)), levels=0:2, labels=c("blue", "yellow", "red"));
myrep <- invrep(myvec);
identical(myvec, rep(myrep$x, myrep$times));
```

Comment: `sort` + `rle` ? Or just `table`? I don't quite get it.

Comment: Dang Joran beat me.  Joran you should probably give that as the answer as I'm guessing it's the best or one of the best.

Comment: @Joran it's just straight `rle` without any `sort`

Comment: Ah, I see now. Looks like Tommy's got you covered.

Comment: Thanks. `rle` is what I was looking for indeed. It's hard to find if you don't know which term to search for :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `rle` function should do the trick:

```
> x <- c(1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
> y <- rle(x)
> y
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 1 4 5 2
  values : num [1:4] 1 2 1 2
> inverse.rle(y)
 [1] 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
> rep(y$values, y$lengths)
 [1] 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

**UPDATE** As @TylerRinker commented, use `as.character` on factors:

```
myvec <- factor(sample.int(3,50,TRUE), levels=1:3, labels=c("blue", "yellow", "red"))
x <- rle(as.character(myvec))
y <- inverse.rle(x)
```

Comment: to work on the factor vector provided I had to convert it to character as in: `rle(as.character(myvec))` +1 and if I could it'd be +2 because I didn't know avout the `inverse.rle`.